# How do i use parameters in cypress custom commands

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

how do i make this work? Im trying to get the id of the object i want to get from the command parameter
[photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APNLX.png)

Comment: Please avoid using the picture of the code and add the code directly to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the template literals for this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('requestReport', (numeFirma, tipRaport) => {
  //some code
  cy.get(`[id=${tipRaport}]`)
  //some code
})
```